# windows phone 8 grid checkbox check and uncheck

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

i have a 100 * 100 grid on one of the page in my app. i have a single checkbox on the top right of the grid.

what i want is that when the user tap or click on the grid first time the checkbox become checked and when i again taps on the grid the checkbox becomes unchecked. how can i achieve it? i am talking about the metro type checkboxes here. or could i use checkbox itself in this manner? is grid the right way to go?

In short i need some guidelines in solving the above problem?

Answer (score 2):

This may work for you

```
 <Grid Height="100" Width="100" Background="Beige" Tap="Grid_Tap" >       
  </Grid>
 <CheckBox  x:Name="gridCheckBox" Content="CheckBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left"            Margin="369,47,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
```

then for making the checkbox checked and unchecked on the tap event of the grid we need to add the following code

```
private void Grid_Tap(object sender, System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs e)
        {
            if (gridCheckBox.IsChecked == true)
            {
                gridCheckBox.IsChecked = false;
            }
            else
            {
                gridCheckBox.IsChecked = true;
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
gridcheckbox.IsChecked = (gridcheckbox.IsChecked == true) ? false : true;
```